# Conditionally execute a task after building a solution with MSBuild + TFS

Tags: tfs, msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm using MSBuild with TFS and I have to build 4 solutions. When the compilation is done I should launch upon to 4 different Exec tasks depending on wherever the compilation was successful or not.

I know how to do that with MSBuild alone using targets with conditions using the var $(BuildBreak) because I can do build solution - check result - exec task - build ... but I don't know how to do that with the TFS extensions ... any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks mates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to check the AfterCompileSolution target defined into the TFS Build extensions

Answer (score 2):

With TFS, the idea is to hook into the TFS eventing service. This guy did it [here](http://www.woodwardweb.com/gadgets/000434.html) for his project.  I can't provide too many details as I am just getting started with TFS, although I am sure its not too far off from dealing with a normal webservice. You should be able to find the details on the eventing service [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507647.aspx)

Comment: I don't agree. I just want to create a build script that uses the TFS targets, nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same targets and conditions with TFS. To implement automation that gets invoked **only** when building with TFS, you can check for the **BuildingInsideVisualStudio** property - it's only defined when (you guessed it) you're building inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Mmmm ... but with MSBuild alone I used the task MSBuild to build the solutions and with TFS I'm just providing the items required by the already implemented CoreCompileSolution ... maybe I don't understand the things rigth.

Comment: What process template are you using in your TFS 2010 build definition (Upgrade or Default)?  I ask this, because if you are using Upgrade, you can continue what you would otherwise have done (CoreCompileSolution) and also use Jim's suggestion to avoid doing so on local builds.  If you are using the Default template, you'll need to edit the build process template.  Create a branch of the DefaultTemplate.xaml first, though.  If you have trouble or need help, let us all know.